# Having trouble getting a Regular expression program running

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerifySerialBayneHarris {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String text;
    String cha;


    System.out.println("Enter a Serial number: ");
    text=input.nextLine();

    if(text.matches("[^-](?!.*--)[A-Za-z0-9-]+[^-]"));{
      System.out.println("Serial number "+text+" verification \nValid");
      System.out.println("Enter a wildchar character: ");
      cha=input.nextLine();
      text= text.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]", cha);
    }

    if(text.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9-]+"));
    System.out.println("Only uppercase , lowercase letters, dashes and numbers are allowed.It should have exactly 2 non-consecutive dashes in the middle. ");
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting both of the expressions running instead of one or the other. There must be something I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Here is my guidelines:
prompts the user to enter a serial number according to the following rules:

- Only uppercase and, lowercase letters, dashes and numbers are allowed.
- It should have exactly 2 non-consecutive dashes in the middle.

Your program should verify that the serial number is valid and if so, prompt the user to enter a wildcard character. It should then display the concealed serial number by masking all of its characters except the dashes using the wild char character

[What code is supposed to look like]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGke.jpg
```

Comment: Remove both `;` at end of `if` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the semi-colon here...

```
if(text.matches("[^-](?!.*--)[A-Za-z0-9-]+[^-]"));{ << HERE

...and...

if(text.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9-]+")); << HERE
```

Your blocks are always executing because the if statement has an empty block due to this.

Comment: Thank you! been looking at this screen too long. Now the only thing not working is the second if statement. Probably something little again. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have minus in character class then it should be first:

[A-Za-z0-9-] shall be [-A-Za-z0-9]

But I would not include the - in the groups and write the pattern as: [A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+){2}

Or with POSIX: \p{Alnum}+(-\p{Alnum}+){2}

If you want to access the 3 segments: (\p{Alnum}+)-(\p{Alnum})-(\p{Alnum})